# Position of the poles of two-point function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, singularities, correlation-functions, propagator, s-matrix-theory

Let $\phi$ be a  **no free** quantum  scalar field and suppose we have the field redefinition $\phi=\psi+F(\psi)$ then the relation between the two point function of $\phi$ and $\psi$ is given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle 0|T(\phi(x) \phi(y))| 0\rangle &=\langle 0|T(\psi(x) \psi(y))| 0\rangle+\langle 0|T(F(\psi(x)) \psi(y))| 0\rangle \\
&+\langle 0|T(\psi(x) F(\psi(y)))| 0\rangle+\langle 0|T(F(\psi(x)) F(\psi(y)))| 0\rangle
\end{aligned} \tag{14}
$$
In this article [The Equivalence theorem and gauge invariance in renormalizable theories](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Erkallosh/KalloshTyutin1972) by  R.Kallosh and I.Tyutin they claim at page 100

> It can be seen that the right-hand side of (14) has only a first-order pole, for which the position coincides with the position of the pole of the propagator $\mathrm{D}_{\psi}$ of the $\psi$ field. This implies that the position of the pole of the propagator $\mathrm{D}\varphi$ of the $\varphi$-field (the left-hand side of $(14)$ coincides with the position of the pole of $\mathrm{D} \psi .$ Indeed, if the positions of the poles of $D_{\varphi}$ and $D_{\psi}$ would not coincide, an infinite series of multiple poles would appear in the right-hand side of $(14)$, but this does not happen.

My questions are:

- Why right-hand side of (14) has only a first-order pole, for which the
  position coincides with the position of the pole of the propagator $\mathrm{D}_{\psi}$ of the $\psi$ field?
- Why would we have an infinite series of multipoles if the position of the poles of $\langle 0|T(\phi(x) \phi(y))| 0\rangle$ and $\langle
     0|T(\psi(x) \psi(y))| 0\rangle$ would not coincide?

Comment: Because $\frac{1}{z - a}$ for $a \neq 0$ has an infinite Laurent expansion.

Comment: @Connor Behan could you expand your comment as an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure how long it would take to add the last bit of rigor. The basic idea is trying to write $\frac{1}{p^2 - m} = \sum_{i = 0}^M \sum_{j = 1}^N \frac{1}{(p^2 - m_i)^j}$. If $M, N$ are finite and none of the $m_i$ are equal to $m$, then the RHS has residue 0 and the LHS has residue 1.

Comment: @Connor Behan the two point function is the one of the interacting theory

Comment: Yeah, so $m$ could be one of the poles in the multi-particle continuum. This probably doesn't make their conclusion harder to "believe" but it does make it harder to prove.